# Spliting .txt file lines in to multi-layered array key value pairs then sorting it

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, flat-file

Since this question has a long explanation, I'll ask the question, then have the explanation below -- Can you sort a multidimensional array by their internal array key value, or is there a better way to get around sorting key value pairs that will have inevitable duplicates, than just using an array?

I am mostly unfamiliar with using PHP and want to learn how to store data.

The *very* simple example I made is just two HTML form inputs for a score and a name and a PHP file to handle the input to be stored in a plain .txt file, which was originally written with the pattern

```
42|John
32|Jane
25|John
```

I was able to successfully split the data, sort it, add the new inputted values then store it all back in the text file to be displayed somewhere else, using the name as the key and the score as the value.

I did all this only to realize that it would only store sort and display the last value associated with each name (i.e.)

```
42|John
32|Jane
25|John
```

would be sorted to

```
32|Jane
25|John
```

because you, obviously, can't have two of the same keys in an array, which is something I completely overlooked.

My solution, currently is to have an extra number that is unique to each name/score pair, which I formatted in the text file as

```
1|42|John
2|32|Jane
3|25|John
```

I then split them into a multidimensional array using this foreach loop

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $lineData = explode("|", $value);
  $scores[$lineData[0]] = array($lineData[1] => $lineData[2]);
}
```

To get this output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [42] => John
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [32] => Jane
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [25] => John
        )
)
```

which avoids overwriting any duplicate names or scores, but leaves me in a position where I can't (to my knowledge) use `arsort()` to sort the array in to highest to lowest.

Comment: Side note: Is there a reason in particular as to why you're not using a database for this? files are a LOT of work. And what you're using now may not be very safe. So, is this for academic purposes or going live?

Comment: Two things: it's a small learning project, so I'm happy to do the extra work to figure it out, and I have not been able to find any help on how to start using a database that makes any sense @Fred-ii-

Comment: I once was using a flat file database for a project that would have made my life a lot easier had I been using an actual (mysql) database. The learning (it) came by necessity and it was the best move I ever made. It took me a few months but I gained a lot of experience with the many Q&A's I found on Stack and elsewhere on the web. If and when you find the time to learn it, believe me that you would have (probably) wished that you'd of learned it sooner. I felt a bit intimidated by a database but that quickly went away. I wouldn't lie to you.

Comment: My setup right now is a raspberry pi running apache, and I haven't found a way to actually setup a database, like the very first steps. I don't even know where to start, since I would like to learn how to use something like mySQL. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Far as I can remember, these places are where I learned from http://www.mysqltutorial.org/ --- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/ --- https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/mysql/ and the official MySQL.com site https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ --- There's also the use of a prepared statement which you really should learn also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement in order to help against an SQL injection. P.s.: I'm still learning ;-) go through some of my answers also.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll definitely look into it! @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome Zachary, enjoy learning; I did :-) *Cheers* and take your time, you'll get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for that, in combination with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). Because the key values are strings, you need to also convert them to integers, for which you can use `array_map("intval", ...)`:

```
foreach($arr as $value) {
  $result[] = explode("|", $value);
}
array_multisort(array_map("intval", array_column($result, 0)), $result);
```

After the above code has run, `$result` will be sorted by the key values:

```
[
    ['25', 'John'],
    ['32', 'Jane'],
    ['42', 'John']
]
```

To reverse the order, apply `array_reverse` to the result.

#### Alternative

You could also decide to sort the original array without conversion to a 2D array, and sort it with a custom sort callback, using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and (again) [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return intval($a) - intval($b);
});
```

Then `$arr` will be sorted to:

```
[
    '25|John',
    '32|Jane',
    '42|John'
]
```

To reverse the order, switch the position of `$a` and `$b` in the sort callback function:

```
    return intval($b) - intval($a);
```

Comment: is it possible to do the opposite of the strcmp() to sort them into descending order? Would it be easier to use an array reversing function?

Comment: sure, either put a minus sign before `strcmp`, or swap both `$a` with `$b` in that expression.

Comment: Okay, also after a quick test I noticed that comparing the strings would put a value of 100|personA, before the 23|personB all all before 4|personC, because it is comparing the string, not the integer value, is there any way to combine the simplicity of your second answer, with the functionality of the first?

Comment: I thought the purpose was to sort by name. What exactly you want to sort by? You want to discard the name, and sort by the numerical value of the first part? Or still something else?

Comment: I have updated my answer to sort on the number part of the line. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: the new intval() version works perfectly, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If we make a small change to your foreach iteration like this:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $lineData = explode("|", $value);
  $scores[] = array('score' => $lineData[1], 'name' => $lineData[2]);
}
```

Your array will have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [score] => 42
            [name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 32
            [name] => Jane
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 25
            [name] => John
        )
)
```

You can use the `uasort` function, which takes the array to sort, and an user-defined function to do the sorting. The code would look like this:

```
function compare($a, $b)
{
    if ($b['score'] == $a['score']) {
        if ($a['name'] == $b['name']) {
            return 0;
        } elseif ($a['name'] < $b['name']) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        return ($b['score'] - $a['score']);
    }
}

print_r($scores);
uasort($scores, 'compare');
print_r($scores);
```

Which gives the following result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 32
            [name] => Jane
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 25
            [name] => John
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [score] => 42
            [name] => John
        )
)
```

When you use a user-defined function for the sorting you need to return one of 3 values (0 of the values as equal, -1 if `$a < $b`, and 1 if `$b > $a`. In this case we're sorting first by score (descending), then by name (ascending). Since you need to order from highest to lowest score, the comparison is `$b` against `$a`, for ascending order is `$a` against `$b`. I didn't consider the extra number necessary. If you need it then change this line:

```
$scores[] = array('score' => $lineData[1], 'name' => $lineData[2]);
```

To this:

```
$scores[$lineData[0]] = array('score' => $lineData[1], 'name' => $lineData[2]);
```